# Can i display a portion of an image in iphone application using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to display portion of image not to display the total image.At first display the full image but after a delay time display the a portion of this image. I can not understand how can i do this. Like we can display portion of text by fixing the dimension of Label.But in case of image how can i do that using sprite or other.

Answer (score 0):

```
[someImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
```

Comment: How can i use this answer.Using sprite or other.Can  you please reply the detail about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the texture rect on the CCSprite.

```
//create a sprite, e.g. myFile is 128x128 pixels
CCSprite* mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"myFile.png"];

//position it somewhere
[mySprite setPosition:ccp(xPos,yPos)];

//show only the first 64x64 square
[mySprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];

//add it to the root
[self addChild:mySprite];
```